FSMContext does not save state (Aiogram)
1.I save the state in the handle_user_input function:
await state.update_data(sent_message_id=sent_message.message_id, user_id=user_id, store_id=store.store_id)
print(f"{user_id} - user_id, {sent_message.message_id} - sent_message.message_id, {store} - store_id")

Output:
7900522738 - user_id, 1618 - sent_message.message_id, Store object (1) - store_id
2.I attempt to retrieve the data from state in the process_store_available function:
user_data = await state.get_data()
user_id = user_data.get('user_id')
print(user_id)
store_id = user_data.get("store_id")
print(store_id)

Output: None None
I’m new to development and need your help.
